# Почему цвета не перестают меняться в p5js?

Tags: javascript

```js
function Randpaint(){
 var Rcolor = color(random(255),random(255),random(255));
 fill(Rcolor)
  noStroke();
}
function RandDraw(rowNum, colNum){
  noStroke();
  var stepX;
  var stepY;
  stepX = width/rowNum;
  stepY = height/colNum;
  for (var i = 0; i < colNum; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < rowNum; j++) {
      Randpaint()
      rect(i * stepX, j * stepY, stepX, stepY);
    }
   }
}
function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500); 
}  

function draw(){
 background(255);
    rectMode(CORNER);
    RandDraw(3, 3) 
}
```

```html
</!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@0.10.2/lib/p5.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 
</body>
</html>
```

P.S нужно, чтобы у квадрата был постоянный цвет

Comment: ну они каждый кадр случайные создаются..

Comment: мне нужно, чтобы у квадрата был какой-то рандомный цвет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот примерно так можно сгенерировать необходимое кол-во цветов один раз, а не каждый кадр:

```js
let colors = [];

function Randpaint(i){
  if (!colors[i])
    colors[i] = color(random(255),random(255),random(255));
 fill(colors[i])
}

function RandDraw(rowNum, colNum){
  noStroke();
  var stepX = width/rowNum;
  var stepY = height/colNum;
  for (var i = 0; i < colNum; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < rowNum; j++) {
      Randpaint(i*rowNum + j)
      rect(i * stepX, j * stepY, stepX, stepY);
    }
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500); 
}  

function draw(){
  RandDraw(3, 3) 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@0.10.2/lib/p5.js"></script>
```